# Audio equivalent of QTMovieView?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos

does anyone know of an audio equivalent of QTMovieView. Something that allows playback and scrubbing of audio files. QTMovieView without the movie...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

QTMovieView, with its height set to `[myMovieView controllerBarHeight]`.